# How to open project in ide from git

Tags: java, git

I downloaded repozitory.zip from github. I had open it in Intelige Idea File / Open / Project directory. But it is not run.  Why it happens?

Comment: Did you unzip it?

Comment: Did you unzip repozitory.zip?

Comment: @Mureinik Jinx lol

Comment: yes i unzip it!

Comment: @Igor does it have the `.idea` folder?

Comment: You might want to clone the repo instead of downloading the zip.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding it directly from git to IDEA.
When you open IDEA and ir shows you all your projects to choose from, select "checkout from git" or something along those lines. Just copy the project URL in there. Than just follow the on-screen instructions (where you want to save it etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you should try to clone it directly..just copy the project url and open the intelliJ idea and (vcs/chekout from version control/git) then go to this path and paste the url and open your project.